# esp8266 Not responding correctly

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to connect an esp8266-01 to an FTDI just to test if my wifi module is responding correctly

- Gnd ==> Gnd
- Tx ==> Rx
- Rx ==> Tx
- Vcc ==> Ch-Pd
- Vcc ==> Vcc
  with a baudrate 115200 .
  The problem is : the responese should be "ok" 'i can't understand why it's not returning  that "ok"
  [image: Sending AT+RST command and the recieved message is in green]

Comment: What is the question? Also show us your connections. What should we do with just this little information that you have given us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTDI's usually don't supply enough energy for the ESPs bootup, you should either get a 3.3V power supply that can deliver 500mA or put a big capacitor(100µF) between 3.3V and GND next to the ESP. This might solve your problem if the ESP is having trouble starting due to not getting enough juice.